# Defining subfolder as a domain in Windows IIS7

Tags: asp.net, .net, wordpress, windows, iis-7

I am trying to setup a Wordpress site as a blog under the same domain as my ASP.NET application.

I have the application at www.URL.com and I want the wordpress site at www.URL.com/blog.

I currently have the blog at localhost:8010, but when I go to define the hostname as www.URL.com/blog, I get an error and cannot proceed.

So my question is where/how do I define the subfolder as a url for the wordpress site?

Answer (score 0):

It is pretty straight forward.  You need to have a binding set to the domain that you are wanting to use and you will need update your hosts file as well.  Follow the instructions [here](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/8d44fb/how-to-access-the-site-using-domain-name-instead-of-localhos/).